# Licensing: Windows Server 2016 with Remote using

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, licensing

I want to buy one windows server 2016 standard license. As this server will locate in Data Center, I do need to remote to access when I want to use it.

The user who manage it is only me (1 user), but sometimes I do need to remote from Mac or PC.

Should I bought RDS CAL license for this case?
And
Do I need to buy User CAL for adding more users?

Could you please answer me what I need to buy to complete this condition?

PS. It might seem duplicate this
[Windows Server 2016 Standard and Remote Desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/825091/windows-server-2016-standard-and-remote-desktop) , but there is some different in details. So, I ask a new question.

Comment: No. Your standard Windows license covers two concurrent remote users for administrative purposes.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Thank you for speedy comment. I'm not quite sure for what I can do about administrative purposes. Can I run C# program or MS Office with administrative purpose user?

Comment: Administrative purpose means to administer the server. You are not allowed to use these users for anything else not related to maintaining this server.